# Get data from http call inside for loop in an Angular 2+ app

Tags: angular, http, observable

I want to call my http request inside a for loop because I only want to execute 1000 items at a time. So I have the following code:

```
getData(IDs: string[]): Observable<any> {
    // IDs is a large array of strings, about 3000 of them

    const results = [];
    const totalData = [];

    // split the IDs array into chunks of 1000
    while (IDs.length) {
      results.push(IDs.splice(0, 1000));
    }

    // loop through the new array with the chunks of 1000 and run the http request
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      const data = this.http.get(`myhttprequest/${results[i]}`);

      totalData.push(data);
    }

    console.log(totalData); 
    // this is just an array of observables when I am looking for an array of data

    return totalData
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but instead of returning an array data, it's just returning an array of observables.

I know it;s because the variables are updating before the data is returned so I've tried using promises and unfortunately I cant get that to work.

How can I get this function to return data instead of observables?

Comment: You have to subscribe to get to send the request.

Answer (score 1):

> Always subscribe!
>
> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call
>   subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true
>   for all HttpClient methods.

Reference [link](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Comment: yeah I cant believe I didnt subscribe, I've done this a million times lol I guess I need some sleep

Comment: It happens with all of us. Take a break. Drink a coffee. :)